# question on uniform convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Assume $p_0=0$ and for all $n\in\{0,1,2,....\}$ we define $P_{n+1}(x)=p_n(x)+\dfrac{x^m-p^m_n(x)}{2}$

then how should I find all natural numbers $m$ such that $\{p_n(x)\}$ be uniformly convergent ?

I proved that for $ m=2$ the sequence is convergent to $|x|$

Thanks for any hint?
I don't want full answer only Hint

Comment: Your recurrence relation is weird. The thing you add to $p_n$ to get $p_{n+1}$ doesn't depend on $n$... So if it's $0$, then you converge to $p_0$ and if not, you diverge to its sign times $+\infty$...

Comment: @ xavierm02 :thanks  i modify it

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo What about the domain, isn't it important. Your sequence of functions should be uniformly convergent on whole $\mathbb{R}$?